# Не могу найти правильный синтаксис удаления GRANT OPTION

Tags: mysql, sql

Пишу `REVOKE GRANT OPTION ON DELETE ON  FROM 'dimalox'@'localhost';`, а mysql выводит это -

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM 'dimalox'@'localhost'' at line 1

В книге так написан запрос, в инете тоже, но mysql выдает ошибку, в чем дело?

Comment: *В книге так написан запрос, в инете тоже* А не надо читать всякую фигню. MySQL наплевать, что там понаписано в книгах и Инетах. У него есть своя документация ([REVOKE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/revoke.html)), и только по ней он работает. По ней отобрать GRANT OPTION можно только у всех привилегий сразу (`REVOKE ALL [PRIVILEGES], GRANT OPTION FROM user_or_role [, user_or_role] ...`), а не у какой-то выбранной привилегии. Решение - отобрать право с опцией, затем дать без опции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`revoke delete, grant option on`clown_info`FROM 'dimalox'@'localhost';` - так работает, но потом при запросе `show grants for dimalox` пишет что у `dimalox` вообще нет привилегий, хотя они остались,удалилась только опция `GRANT OPTION`.

Поправочка:
Очень странно себя ведет MySQL, после того как вышел из MySQL и зашел обратно за пользователя `dimalox`, все привилегии исчезли.
Так что,как ответил Akina в комментариях, нужно отобрать право с опцией, а потом дать без опций:

`revoke select on govno.* from 'dimalox'@'localhost';`

`grant select on govno.* to 'dimalox'@'localhost';`

Но проблема со странным поведением остается...